# ¿Cómo paso este selector de jQuery a JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este selector y quisiera pasarlo de jQuery a JS. ¿Alguien sabe como?

```
$("id^=row).css("widht", '75%')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buenas tienes que usar `querySelector` para coger el elemento y después cambiarle el estilo.

```
const element1 = document.querySelector(`[id^="row"]`);
element1.style.width = "75%";
```

**Edit:**

Como bien menciona @Triby hay que considerar que pueda haber múltiples elementos con el mismo inicio de ID. El siguiente caso serviría para ello:

```
const elemenst1 = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="row"]');
for(var i = 0; i < elemenst1.length; i++){
    elemenst1[i].style.width = "75%";
}
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero habría que considerar que hay múltiples elementos que tienen ID iniciando con `row`.

Comment: Muchas Gracias SrMiamibeach y Triby!

Comment: @Tridy es verdad había, perdón leído mal tu comentario, aun asi  sigue sirviendo para tu ejemplo